# Asterisk 1.6.2.20. PHP. How to get list of phone numbers that calls in current time?

Tags: php, asterisk

We have asterisk server and I need to get numbers that calls in current time. I try to use [php agi](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/) library, but maximum that I got is the list of channels.

```
$agi_manager = new AGI_AsteriskManager(null, $agi_config);
$connect = $agi_manager->connect();
$result = $agi_manager->command('core show channels');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what you need.

Now you must parse the table and extract SIP peers from it.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get phone number from SIP peers?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't, because it depends on your dialplan. A peer can be reached via any number you want, if you've written that in your dialplan. And of course in general you can't say what number can be used to reach this or that peer. It's even possible that you reached a peer not via number, but via IVR (for example). In this case the peer obviously can live without "phone number" at all.